# How to get last Monday from a specific date

Tags: php, date

I am trying to get the date of Monday from a specific date.
I try to use

```
strtotime("last monday")
```

But it's giving me current last Monday date not from a specific date.
Like I want to know the last Monday date on 2020-10-11 which is 2020-10-05

Comment: does `-2 weeks monday` do anything to help?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for the date of the most recent monday before a given date?

Comment: Yes this solved my problem not exactly but yes this will help me

Comment: @John.M Yes exactly

Comment: Ok, perhaps use date(w,strtotime("2020-01-11")) to get the numeric representation of the day for that specific date. Then use that value to count back to Monday (1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the class [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to create an object at the desired date, and then [modify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) it :

```
$date = new DateTime('2020-10-11');
$date->modify('last monday');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // output is 2020-10-05
```

---

As pointed [jspit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7271221/jspit) in comments, if the current date is monday **and then if this date should be returned**, a simple check can be added to avoid returning the wrong date :

```
$date = new DateTime('2020-10-11');
if ($date->format('N') != 1) // If the date isn't already monday
    $date->modify('last monday');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // output is 2020-10-05
```

Comment: Note: If $date is a Monday, e.g. 2020-10-12 the above code also gives the Monday 2020-10-05 and not the Monday 2020-10-12 itself.

Comment: @jspit good point. However, is last monday required or current day? This can be fixed with `if ($date->format('N') == 1) { /* we are monday */ }`

Comment: or date_create('2020-10-12')->modify('1 Day')->modify('last Monday')